# Increment animation doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to scale up a circle when a variable increment.

But the animation will never trigger up
  I'm proceeding in this way:

```js
animations: [
    trigger('popAnimation', [
      state('closed', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })),
      state('open', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(300)),
    ]),
    trigger('counterChange', [
      state(':increment', style({ transform: 'scale(1.8)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(300)),
    ])
  ],
```

For increment of the variable

```js
bag.products.reduce((prev, product) => this.numberOfProducts = prev + product.quantities, 0);
```

And in HTML I use in this way:

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-md-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="circle"
             [@counterChange]="numberOfProducts">
          {{numberOfProducts}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I can't really figure out the error.

## UPDATE:

---

The problem has been solved, I change approach.
  The animation was not triggered by increment, so when `reduce` starts, I set a variable for the `state` of animation and in `setTimeout` set to another state.

```js
trigger('counterChange', [
      transition(`${AnimationShoppingBag.Clicked} => *`,
        (
          animate(400, keyframes([
            style({ transform: 'scale(1.8)' }),
            style({ transform: 'rotate(45deg)' }),
            style({ transform: 'rotate(-45deg)' })
          ]))
        )),
    ])
```

```js
this.animationShoppingBag = AnimationShoppingBag.Clicked;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.animationShoppingBag = AnimationShoppingBag.End;
        bag.products.reduce((prev, product) => this.numberOfProducts = prev + product.quantities, 0);
      }, 600);
```